# Make a new Data frame by filtering an old Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I want to make a dataset such that it has all unique `['contentId']`**

I used the following code:

```
l = df2['contentId']
l = list(set(l))
print(l)
print(len(l))

df2_row = df2.loc(df2['contentId'].isin(l))
df2_row.head()
```

But is gives an error:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxWh9.png)

What do I do?

Comment: use square brackets: `df2.loc[df2['contentId'].isin(l)]`

Comment: `df2[df2['contentId'].isin(l)]`